# Nestjs Repository Pattern with Typeorm Transactions

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I've been using Nestjs with the repository pattern, so I inject the repository into the Service as below:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Foo)
    private fooRepository: Repository<Foo>,
 ) {}
}
```

And I've been using the repository as follows:

```
async createFoo(createFooDto: CreateFooDto) {
  const foo = new Foo();
  foo.Something = createFooDto.Something;
  foo.Anything = createFooDto.Anything; 

  await this.fooRepository.save(foo);
}
```

Now if I want to use transactions, the docs recommend doing it by injecting a Connection object on the service. My question is this: Is it ok for me to change the constructor above to:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Foo)
    private fooRepository: Repository<Foo>,
    @InjectConnection()
    private connection: Connection
 ) {}
}
```

In this case, the majority of the methods would be using the fooRepository and some methods that needs transaction would be using the connection object (connection.manager.transaction(() => {...}) or connection.createQueryRunner() ...)

Or should I inject only the connection and create the fooRepository from the connection.manager all the time? What is the problem in having one repository and one connection at the same time on the service of my class? Is there a problem?

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221128/how-to-use-transactions-with-nestjs-repositories

Have you found an answer for your question?