# How to use transactions with NestJs Repositories?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Assuming I have this Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(A)
    private aRepository: Repository<A>,
    @InjectRepository(B)
    private bRepository: Repository<B>,
  ) {}

  doSomething() {
     // TX: begin()
    this.aRepository.save(...);
    this.bRepository.save(...);
    // TX: commit()
  }
}
```

How to start a transaction and commit it?

Answer (score 0):

For transactions, it is not mandatory to use the injected repositories. You can do something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(A)
    private aRepository: Repository<A>,
    @InjectRepository(B)
    private bRepository: Repository<B>,
  ) {}

  async doSomething() {
    await getManager().transaction(async (manager) => {
      // TX: begin()
      await manager.getRepository(A).save(...);
      await manager.getRepository(B).save(...);
      // TX: commit()
    });
  }
}
```

Look for more info in [Typeorm Transactions](https://typeorm.io/#/transactions)